# Setting options in "PDF Export Options" to export an atlas to PDF using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export, pdf, atlas

While saving an atlas as PDF in QGIS, I can manually change the settings shown the image using "PDF Export Settings" window.

[image]

How can I set those options using PyQGIS?

Minimal code:

```
layout_manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName('LAYOUT_NAME')

layout_exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)    
layout_exporter.exportToPdf(path, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting those options using PyQGIS requires using `QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()` instance.

`pdf_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()`

Then;

1. For "*Always export as vector*"
   `pdf_settings.forceVectorOutput = True` or `False`.
2. For "*Export RDF metadata*"
   `pdf_settings.exportMetadata = True` or `False`.
3. "*Text export*" options:

   - For "*Always Export Text as Paths*"
     `pdf_settings.textRenderFormat = QgsRenderContext.TextFormatAlwaysOutlines`
   - For "*Always Export Text as Text Objects*"
     `pdf_settings.textRenderFormat = QgsRenderContext.TextFormatAlwaysText`
4. For "*Disable tiled raster layer exports*"
   `pdf_settings.rasterizeWholeImage = True` or `False`.

[image]

```
layout_manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = layout_manager.layoutByName('LAYOUT_NAME')

pdf_settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()

pdf_settings.forceVectorOutput = True` # default False
pdf_settings.exportMetadata = False # default True
pdf_settings.rasterizeWholeImage = True # default False
pdf_settings.textRenderFormat = QgsRenderContext.TextFormatAlwaysText
# OR pdf_settings.textRenderFormat = QgsRenderContext.TextFormatAlwaysOutlines # default

layout_exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)    
layout_exporter.exportToPdf(path, pdf_settings)
```